# MobileBert from TensorFlow Lite in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I downloaded MobileBert model from TensorFlow - the Questions and Answers model based on TensorFlow Lite for mobile devices from here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/bert_qa/overview

The example how to use it provided only for Android. Can anybody advise how to use this model in Python (for testing purposes). I followed recommendations on how to use TensorFlow Lite API, but I need to figure out how to modify it to use for MobileBert:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="mobilebert_float_20191023.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)

input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.int32)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this project : https://github.com/samsgates/MobileBERT
It is basically designed to run the Google's model that you mentioned. I managed to run it with TF 1.14 along with other dependencies installed (**sentencepiece**, **bert-for-tf2**, both are available from PiP). The only thing I had to tweak is to remove the *tf.dtypes.cast()* wrappers over the input/output tensors. E.g. for the inputs I changed

```
input_ids = tf.dtypes.cast(self.get_ids(stokens),tf.int32)
```

to

```
input_ids = self.get_ids(stokens).astype('int32')
```

And for the outputs I changed

```
end = tf.argmax(end_logits,output_type=tf.dtypes.int32).numpy()[0]
```

to simple

```
end = np.argmax(end_logits)
```

That did the trick for me. Hope this helps!